# how to use different decorator from parent class in child class in django?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 class based views `MyFirstView` and `MySecondView`. I want these 2 views to use different decorators from each other. I have been googling for the solution almost an hour now but still can't find any answers to this. So I'm here asking for help.

```py
@method_decorator(my_first_decorator, name="dispatch")
class MyFirstView(UpdateView):
    # some attributes
    # some methods


@method_decorator(my_second_decorator, name="dispatch")
class MySecondView(MyFirstView):
    # some attributes
```

I have been trying to give the different decorator to the views like showed above but for some reason `MySecondView` still using `MyFirstView`'s decorator.

I also tried to override the dispatch method but without any success.

```py
class MyFirstView(UpdateView):

    @method_decorator(my_first_decorator)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    # some attributes
    # some methods


class MySecondView(MyFirstView):

    @method_decorator(my_second_decorator)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    # some attributes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach seems right, but you have to skip one parent in the MRO:

```
class MySecondView(MyFirstView):

    @method_decorator(my_second_decorator)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyFirstView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way, the `super` calls the plain undecorated original implementation instead of the tainted one from its direct super class.